# Changing value of superclass variable in all subclasses

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc

I have a superclass which is inherited by all subclasses. I want to declare a member variable in the super class, such that if one subclass changes that member variable, then the changes of that member variables are reflected in all subclasses as well as the superclass itself. Is there some way by which I may do so in C++.

```
class superClass1 {
public:
    int test;
};

class subclass1 : public superClass1 {
public:
    void func()
    {
        test=10;
        cout<<"1. value of test="<<test<<"\n";
    }
};

class subclass2: public superClass1 {
public:
    void func1()
    {
        cout<<"2. value of test="<<test<<"\n";
    }
};
```

Now the outputs which I am getting are:

```
1. value of test=10
2. value of test=1701602675
```

My expected output is:

```
1. value of test=10
2. value of test=10
```

Although I want the values of both the tests to be same, yet they are coming to be different. Is there some way by which I may modify the super class variable in any of the subclass and the value of that super class variable gets reflected across all other subclasses.

The gcc compiler which I am using has the version: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.4-6ubuntu2) 4.6.4

EDIT: I tried making test as statis within superClass1 but it is giving me the error: undefined reference to `superClass1::test'

Comment: Are you aware that a class holds no values, only the objects does? And you could use `static`.

Comment: @deviantfan Thanks. I tried but it is giving me the error: undefined reference to `superClass1::test'

Answer (score 3):

Declare the variable as `static` in the base class and define it in some cpp.module if the class itself is defined in a header. For example

```
class superClass1{
public:
 static int test; // declaration
};

int superClass1::test; // definition
```

The variable will be zero-initialized by the compiler. If you want that it would be initialized by some other value then you should specify the initializer explicitly. for example

```
int superClass1::test = 10;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what is the reason for defining a static variable?

Comment: @Steg Verner Defining a static variable means allocating memory for it where you are going to store its values.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `test` member as `static`. In this case it´ll be shared among all objects.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it is giving me the error: undefined reference to `superClass1::test'

Comment: Yes, because you have to define it as well. Like `int superClass1::test = 0;`

Comment: Ok. where should I define it.

Comment: If your class definition is divided into `.h` and `.cpp` files then do it in `.cpp` file.

Comment: Ok. Can you please illustrate with an example. I am really not able to understand as to where should I define "test"

Comment: The code you wrote in the question. Is it your header or `.cpp` file?

Comment: OK. Then just after your `superClass1` definition add line `int superClass1::test;` or (if you want to initialize it with some value) `int superClass1::test = 42;`